# playing wav audio file in C++ and QT

Tags: c++, qt, audio, wav

I am reading a .wav file in C and then I am trying to play the audio file using some of the QT functions. Here is how I read the file:

```
FILE *fhandle=fopen("myAudioFile.wav","rb");
fread(ChunkID,1,4,fhandle);
fread(&ChunkSize,4,1,fhandle);
fread(Format,1,4,fhandle);
fread(Subchunk1ID,1,4,fhandle);
fread(&Subchunk1Size,4,1,fhandle);
fread(&AudioFormat,2,1,fhandle);
fread(&NumChannels,2,1,fhandle);
fread(&SampleRate,4,1,fhandle);
fread(&ByteRate,4,1,fhandle);
fread(&BlockAlign,2,1,fhandle);
fread(&BitsPerSample,2,1,fhandle);
fread(&Subchunk2ID,1,4,fhandle);
fread(&Subchunk2Size,4,1,fhandle);
Data=new quint16 [Subchunk2Size/(BitsPerSample/8)]; 
fread(Data,BitsPerSample/8,Subchunk2Size/(BitsPerSample/8),fhandle); 
fclose(fhandle);
```

So my audio file is inside `Data`. Each element of `Data` is unsigned 16-bit Integer.

To play the sound I divide each 16-bit unsigned Integer into two characters and then every 3 ms (using a timer) I send 256 characters to the audio card.
Assume `myData` is a character array of 256 characters I do this (every 3 ms) to play the sound:

```
m_output->write(myData, 256);
```

Also `m_output` is defined as:

```
m_output = m_audioOutput->start();
```

and `m_audioOutput` is defined as:

```
m_audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(m_Outputdevice, m_format, this);
```

And the audio format is set correctly as:

```
m_format.setFrequency(44100); 
m_format.setChannels(2);
m_format.setSampleSize(16);
m_format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt ); 
m_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
m_format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
```

However, when I try to run the code I hear some noise which is very different from the real audio file.
Is there anything I am doing wronge?

Thanks,
TJ

Comment: What kind of timer are you using?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're reading your file that way? Otherwise you could just use the simple way: QSound::play("myAudioFile.wav") or better using QAudioOutput reading with QFile as the documentation suggests.

Comment: @Anthony: does it matter what type of timer I am using?

Comment: @LucaCarlon: I want to do some signal processing before directly playing the audio. Is there anything wrong the way I play the audio?

Comment: It matters because if the timer is inaccurate then your approach will cause the sound to mess up. It's really quite hard to get something to happen exactly three (or any other number of) milliseconds.

Comment: I use QTimer and it is quite accurate based on my measurements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using QTimer. QTimer is absolutely not going to allow you to run code every three milliseconds exactly, regardless of the platform you're using. And if you're off by just one sample, your audio is going to sound horrible. According to the [QTimer docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTimer.html#accuracy-and-timer-resolution):

> ...they are not guaranteed to time out at the exact value specified. In
>   many situations, they may time out late by a period of time that
>   depends on the accuracy of the system timers.

and

> ...the accuracy of the timer will not equal [1 ms] in many real-world situations.

As much as I love Qt, I wouldn't try to use it for signal processing. I would use another framework such as [JUCE](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php).

Comment: I guess you are right, what would be the most stable timer? Does juce have an accurate timer?

Comment: I don't think timers are the way to go for signal processing. You shouldn't have to go that low level. Anyways, I would have a look at JUCE and also [here](https://github.com/vinniefalco/DSPFilters) (a collection of classes for DSP that uses JUCE). I also highly recommend [PD](http://puredata.info/). It is very easy and extremely powerful.